# $f$ and $|f|$ are analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ and $|f|$ are analytic on a domain(open and connected) $D \subset \mathbb{C}$ , then show $f$ is constant on $D$.
What I did:
Since $|f|$ is analytic and since it is a real valued function then its derivative is zero in the domain and hence $|f|$ is constant. Thus we must have the derivative of $f$ is $0$ ( which I know how to prove). Thus $f$ must be constant.
Is my logic correct? Thanks

Comment: How can you go from the statement that $|f|$ is constant to the conclusion that $f$ is constant? Notice that if $\theta$ is a real variable then $|e^{i\theta}|$ is constant, but $e^{i\theta}$ is not constant.

Comment: How can a real-valued function (such as $|f|$) be analytic on an open set? If its derivative is $0$ everywhere, then it is analytic. But suppose $|f|'(a)\ne0.$ The the rate of change of $|f|$ as its argument moves in the direction of $i/|f|'(a)$ is a pure imaginary number. Thus the function will not remain real as the argument moves in that direction.

Comment: @michaelHardy If |f| is constant on domain(open and connected) then the derivative of f is 0 throughout the domain.

Comment: @MichaelHardy The example you gave is not an analytic function.

Comment: @JohnSmith : Which example? Do you mean $\theta\mapsto e^{i\theta}\text{?}$ That is analytic if one does not restrict $\theta$ to being a real number. But my question is how did you go from the statement that  $|f|$ is constant to the conclusion that $f$ is constant. One can cite some simple propositions that would imply that if one assumes $|f|$ is analytic in some open set, but how to prove propositions of that kind seems to be the very thing that the question is about.

Comment: In other words, I would require you to be explicit about how you did that. Maybe you could say "By proposition 61 in the textbook" or something like that (but if you're posting here you would have to tell us what that says).

Comment: @MichaleHardy If |f| is constant then f has derivative 0. This is pretty easy result to prove.